# Only if contains >< /!a-zA-Z or some of them with regular expression

Tags: javascript, c#, regex, contains

I need to check string if contains >< /!a-zA-Z or some of them (Also contains space). The only thing I know is a-zA-Z i need an example in C# or Javascript.

Answer (score 2):

Use a "character class".

```
/[>< \/!a-zA-Z]/
```

Note that I've escaped the forward slash, since we're using forward slashes as delimiters.